# Timestamp env variable or argument for telegraf configuration

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, toml, telegraf-inputs-plugin

I am using the inputs.http plugin of Telegraf in order to import data from an API to influxdb. The API requires a time filter in the body of a POST request and responds with data between that time filter. I want to periodically call this API and retrieve data for the past 10 or so seconds. So I need to include the current timestamp in the body of the POST request. **Can I pass the current server timestamp to telegraf.conf in the form of an environment variable or a command line argument?** What I have attempted so far is using an environment variable in the telegraf.conf file as shown below. It did not work.

```
[[inputs.http]]
  #URL
  urls = ["url"]

  #http method
  method = "POST"

  ## Optional HTTP headers
  headers = {"cache-control" =  "no-cache","content-type" =  "application/json"}

  ## HTTP entity-body to send with POST/PUT requests.
  #body = "{\"measurement\":\"measurement_name\", \"time_filter\":[1593068400, 1593068800]}"
  body = "{\"measurement\":\"measurement_name\", \"time_filter\":[1593562547, ${date +%s}]}"

  #Data from HTTP in JSON format
  data_format = "json"
```

I then run the command below

```
$telegraf -config telegraf.conf
```

and receive a 400 error. If I replace the body line (includes variable) with the line above it (no variable) everything works fine.

Comment: Matthew, did you get anywhere with this ?

Comment: No, I did not. Sorry.